# Software to Detect Device Missing from Network?

Tags: networking, monitoring, alert

I have several small Android tablets that I am going to deploy in a manufacturing environment. Each one will be assigned to an individual, but I'd still like to have some way of detecting if the devices are off of my network for longer than, say, a week or two. This will help identify theft as well as ensuring that the devices are actually being used. My search for a program that does this has been fruitless so far. Any ideas on what would fill this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a local instance of PRTG Network Monitor that would allow you to set basic ping return thresholds that will alert you by email or text message that the device has not reported in. Its lightweight and I use it for temporary demo devices on our campus.

https://www.paessler.com/prtg

It is free for less than 100 sensors. Given your intended use, I cannot see you hitting this threshold. It would, however, require you to set a static IP address for the device.

Comment: It looks like this will be the best solution for my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You want an MDM solution that can do geo-fencing and asset reporting. This is a pretty common set of features.

Comment: Office365, Exchange on prem, Goole apps all have MDM features

Comment: I like the idea, but it seems overkill for my particular situation